# Git installed via Homebrew has suddenly stopped working

Tags: macos, git, homebrew

I have already installed git some time ago, now I want to update it, but I get error `Error: git not installed`. How to fix it?

```
git --version
git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)


type -a git
git is /usr/bin/git


which git
/usr/bin/git


brew upgrade git
Error: git not installed


brew uninstall git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git


brew info git
git: stable 2.23.0 (bottled), HEAD
Distributed revision control system
https://git-scm.com
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✘, pcre2 ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 160,476 (30 days), 446,588 (90 days), 1,804,394 (365 days)
install_on_request: 149,046 (30 days), 415,976 (90 days), 1,656,545 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Just uninstall it and reinstall it.

This is a rare occurrence, but sometimes this happens in Homebrew. What I do is uninstall the package like this:

```
brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies git
```

Then reinstall it like this:

```
brew install git
```

Remember, package installed items are easily removable and reinstall-able; so always lean on that fact to clear up an issue before doing anything else.

If somehow that still results in nothing, I would recommend removing all Homebrew packages and reinstalling them as follows using this command:

```
brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies $(brew list);
```

Or do a similar thing this way:

```
brew list -1 | xargs brew uninstall -f
```

And then just reinstall things as needed the usual, `brew install` way.